# Why the progressBar is getting to 97% and never to 100%?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= lines.Length; i++)
    {
        if (lines[i].Contains("Code"))
        {
            string countryCode = lines[i].Substring(15);
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.DownloadFileCompleted += Client_DownloadFileCompleted;
                Uri uri = new Uri("http://api.sat24.com/animated/" + countryCode + "/infraPolair/1/JerusalemStandardTime/1897199");
                client.DownloadFile(uri, @"c:\temp\" + countriesNames[countCountries] + ".gif");
            }

            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i * 100 / lines.Length);
            countCountries++;
        }
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    label1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";
}
```

All the gifs will download fine but it will stay on 97%. I could set in the backgroundworker completed event the progressBar value to 100, but that's not a real solution i think.

Another problem is how can i handle the first gif downloaded ? It's animated gifs and i want that once the first one is downloaded to display it in pictureBox1. Should i use for that the WebClient download completed event ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will throw exception at last iteration here. and you are probably not aware of that.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= lines.Length; i++)
```

Because you must iterate from `0` to `i < lines.Length`. (Note that array indexes are 0-based)

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
```

And also change the report progress to this

```
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i * 100 / (lines.Length - 1));
```

---

Another note that I missed which is mentioned by @Peter in his answer is to move report progress line outside of if statement.

```
if (lines[i].Contains("Code") {...}
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i * 100 / (lines.Length-1));
```

Comment: Got to 98% with this changes.

Comment: @DanielDejunior check with debugger. probably your code throws exception somewhere. and basically it cant continue. put breakpoint and go step by step to see where you get error.

Answer (score 1):

Your progress is inside your if. Place it outside the if, and it will report the correct process. I guess the last few lines do not contain the word Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    if (lines[i].Contains("Code"))
    {
        string countryCode = lines[i].Substring(15);
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.DownloadFileCompleted += Client_DownloadFileCompleted;
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://api.sat24.com/animated/" + countryCode + "/infraPolair/1/JerusalemStandardTime/1897199");
            client.DownloadFile(uri, @"c:\temp\" + countriesNames[countCountries] + ".gif");
        }
        countCountries++;
    }
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i * 100 / (lines.Length-1));
}
```

Comment: good note. but `i = 1; i <= lines.Length` is still wrong. you forgot to fix that ;)

Comment: Yepp you are correct, then the calculation is also wrong because i will never be Length but (Length-1).

Answer (score -1):

I could focus on `100 / lines.Length` . Try `(double)100 / (double)lines.Length`